# Access wcf service with custome binding using php soapclient

Tags: php, wcf, soap-client

I have a wcf service and I can access that using soapclient in php, Now I am going to use load balancer and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730128(v=vs.110).aspx) article is saying 'set false to keepAliveEnabled'. Therefore I used customeBindings. but the issue is now I can not access the service using php. I saw many articles saying use basicHttpBindings, but I can not use that method. I am getting this error.

```
Caught exception: Cannot process the message because the content type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-16LE'.
```

Therefore I added soapversion to SoapClient

```
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('uri' => 'http://tempuri.org/','soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,'trace' => true,'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,'keep_alive' => false));
```

then I am getting this error.

```
Caught exception: The SOAP action specified on the message, '', does not match the HTTP SOAP Action, 'http://Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples/Service1'
```

This is the customBinding I used.

```
 <customBinding>
       <binding name="HttpBinding" keepAliveEnabled="False"/>
    </customBinding>
```

Can anyone tell me how to resolve this. Or any other way to do this. Thanks

Comment: Having the same issue. Is anyone having solution of this problem?